# How would i go about to attache a MongoDb Collection to a Java View

Tags: java, swing, mongodb, field, morphia

How would i go about to attache a `collection` of MongoDb logging `Document` to a `JTable` or `JList` or even a `JTextPane`. The state of all `Document` in the `Collection` must be shown in real time sorted by insertion `Date`. When a new `Documents` is inserted the View must reflect that.

This can of course be done by writing the code. What i look for is some existing technics for this

Comment: What have you done so far to incorporate MongOB into your project?

Comment: I use mongo and morphia in production and it's grate. It's backing up the SPRIID app I have in google play. I have this UserLog.class Collection that i want to find a way to monitor in real time

Comment: MongoDB doesn't have change notification for documents (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5042). So, you'd need to implement a cached polling system on your own. Other than that -- it's not at all clear what you want for help?

Comment: change notification is something to look forward to. I have this UserLog Collection that i want to find a way to monitor in real time.

Answer (score 0):

The java display should be easy. Just implement a Table model for your JTable, that displays the field from the DBObject returned by MongoDB. Then just trigger a redraw, when new data is available.

Why would you want to use a Text-Pane?

Comment: Yes this is what i did today but outputting it to JTextPane because it's IMHO better when it comes to styled text, highlighting text. Especially if the row counts are high. I have a feeling also Having many cellrenderer in JTable will be slow.